# Java Wildcard capture

Tags: java

```
<T extends Number> void m1(List<T> list) {
    list.add(list.get(0)); 
}

void m2(List<? extends Number> list) {
    list.add(list.get(0)); 
}
```

I found difficult to understand the difference between above two methods.
First method `m1()` compiles successfully, but method `m2()` produces a compiler error:

> The method `add(capture#1-of ? extends Number)` in the type `List<capture#1-of ? extends Number>` is not applicable for the arguments `(capture#2-of ? extends Number)`

Comment: TypeErasure....

Answer (score 2):

Because you cant add an iten on a list of type with upper bounds! You could have a List or List, where one doesnt fit in the other for modifications operations!

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

In this case, the variable list could have any type in instance that extends `Number`. So you can pass it in your method, for example. But there, you don't really know which the type could be. You could have a `ArrayList<Integer>` and saying to it add a new `Double`. In compile time makes sense, because `Double` extends `Number`, but in runtime the list could no be of this type and throw an Exception.

Just remember that, when you use the upper bounds, `<? extends T>`, you **can't** modify the list, just read it! There is the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) (see *Wildcards* chapter contents - *Upper Bounded Wildcards*, *Lower Bounded Wildcards* etc.)

Comment: "In compile time makes sense", but why method m2 is compile error, not runtime error?