# Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#2-of ? extends Number to T

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Stack {
    private LinkedList<? extends Number> stack;

    public <T extends Number> void push(T t){
        stack.add(t);
    }

    public <T extends Number>T pop(){
        return stack.removeLast();
    }
}
```

Both add and remove last method are giving compile time error. Please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Error at push -

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Number) in the type
>   LinkedList is not applicable for the
>   arguments (T)

Error at pop -

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#2-of ? extends Number to T

Comment: Please [edit]  your question and include the errors. You should also describe what it is you are trying to achieve, as it stands, this question is off-topic.

Comment: `?` is not some `T`, just use `Stack<T extends Number>` and `T` everywhere in the class

Comment: You do not need the generics in this case. You could replace them with the upper bound `Number`. The code would most likely (even if it would compile) lead to some `ClassCastException`s. Imagine you `push(...)` a `Double`, but try to `pop()` an `Integer`...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40506817/java-wildcard-capture

Comment: As an aside: you should take a look at the [PECS-mnemonic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). Since your `Stack` is producer and consumer, you most probably want to use either `Number` or make your whole class generic with some `<T extends Number>` as described in the answers below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?` isn't the same thing as `T` and you haven't defined `T` in your class (only for those methods). Therefore I suggest you make the whole `Stack` class generic as such:

```
public class Stack<T extends Number> {
  private LinkedList<T> stack;
```

Then you can use `T` in your `push()` and `pop()` methods.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make your whole class generic? like so:

```
public class Stack <T extends Number>{
    private LinkedList<T> stack;

    public void push(T t){
        stack.add(t);
    }

    public T pop(){
        return stack.removeLast();
    }

}
```